# npm ERR! cb is not a function

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3-dev,
I try installing Laravel Elixir,and I follow the documentation,https://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir

When I run `npm install --no-bin-links`,
there is something wrong,
and `npm install` is the same result.
as follow:

```
$ npm install --no-bin-links
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail o                                                                                                  n node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible                                                                                                  . Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                   to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                   to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade                                                                                                   to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail o                                                                                                  n node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible                                                                                                  . Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js                                                   " "install" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0-nightly2016080329e49fc286
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5

npm ERR! cb is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js                                                   " "install" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0-nightly2016080329e49fc286
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5


npm ERR! cb is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-demo\npm-debug.log
```

What should I do?

Comment: Using windows and npm is a bad idea.  There are a lot of issue with the file system.  I recommend using a vagrant virtual environment like Homestead a try.

Comment: Are you intentionally using a nightly version of node?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you are using Node v7 nightly. This has (or had?) breaking changes in it, including requirements that certain synchronous functions supply callbacks that weren't required in v6. An error that "cb is not a function" sure sounds suspiciously like that problem.

Use either the current or LTS version of Node.js. As of this writing, the current version of Node.js is 6.3.1. The LTS version is 4.4.7.

Don't use the nightly version unless you have a good reason to, such as trying to test something specific. If you use a nightly version, be prepared to have problems you will need to dive in and investigate.